# Anuglar 2 - Difference between Shared Service and Normal Service Component

Tags: angular2-services

Can any one help me understand Difference between Shared Service and Normal Service Component, are they same or use with particular significance.

Services in angular meant to use across multiple components/modules, so my question is what is difference between that normal service in angular and Shared service ?

Answer (score -1):

Shared component and Normal component is a very good way of reusing components , let me tell how :

1. Taking the case that you have a bootstrap modal ( or say a simple alert if you are not aware of a modal ) and you have to use it in Component A , B , C , D ,
2. So , always mentioning it in every component individually is not a good scope , so what we do is , we make a common sharable component of a modal (alert) which can be reused in the all four components rather than repeating the modals in every component

But in the case of a normal component , you dont cannot share such things

Please feel free to add any further question or clarification , 
cheers!

Comment: thanks for revert, but my quesion is about services, services in angular meant to use across multiple components/modules, so my question is what is difference between that normal service in angular and Shared service ?